# When to use JavaScript in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am a beginner in ASP.Net. We have Validation Controls in ASP.Net. But I want to know, In which scenarios we need to use JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript will provide you with the ability to do client side validation which will allow you to save server roundtrip and makes your application less chatty, which is generally a good thing.  I believe the validation controls in ASP.NET do have the ability to do client side validation as well (it will generate the necessary JavaScript and save you the work).

Comment: There are a lot of sites that do this.  Just plug in learn javascript in a search engine and you should find them.

Answer (score 1):

Specially in Validation approaches if you need to validate a email address in ASP.NET you need to send a server request and get the resonance

in JS you can validate in client side with out sending a server request

Answer (score 1):

When you want validation to happen on the client side.  That is, validate before anything is sent to the server (ie - form submission) so its more responsive and doesn't waste server resource unnecessariy.

This can be done when a submit button is clicked but before the actual request is sent, when a certain input box loses focus, keypresses on a textbox to keep letters out of a numeric input, or pretty much on any event.

Comment: So JavaScript is mainly used to done the validation in Client Side. So We can use JavaScript in all the Scenarios.

Comment: im not sure what you're getting at.  i dont recommend considering this a substitution for server side validation

Comment: Ok jon. thank u so much for your contribution. It will be helpful for my career.